# How to collapse grouped information spread across different columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, tidyverse

I have an issue that should have a very straight forward solution but I can't seem to find it. Basically I have observations nested within district*county but their values of candidate are wrong and the information for a single candidate is spread through multiple columns. The original dataset has the same problem but instead of only four non.grouping variables it has 500+.

But here it's what it looks like now:

```
current_df
   county district candidate  name votes party
1    E100        1         1  john    NA  <NA>
2    E100        1         2  <NA>   100  <NA>
3    E100        1         3  <NA>    NA     D
4    E101        2         4 maria    NA  <NA>
5    E101        2         5  <NA>   200  <NA>
6    E101        2         6  <NA>    NA     I
7    E202        1         7   tom    NA  <NA>
8    E202        1         8  <NA>    78  <NA>
9    E202        1         9  <NA>    NA     R
10   E204        3        10  jose    NA  <NA>
11   E204        3        11  <NA>   120  <NA>
12   E204        3        12  <NA>    NA  <NA>
```

And this is what I'd want to have:

```
target_df <- data.frame(county = c("E100",  "E101","E202", "E204"),
                         district= c(1, 2, 1, 3),
                         candidate = c(1, 1, 2, 1),
                         name = c("john","maria",
                                  "tom", "jose"),
                         votes = c(100,
                                   200,
                                   78,
                                   120),
                         party = c( "D",
                                    "I",
                                    "R",
                                    NA))
```

Again, if there is a solution that doesn't build on the fact that there are only 4 variables other than county and district that's ideal because I have many in many dataframe. For reference, `candidate` is just the ordered indicator of the candidate within each district.

Also, some rows, as is the case of that with `candidate == "jose"` in `target_df` have NA for their party value. This is just a function of the data's context.

I've tried way to many things and can't still find something doing it well. Any pointers very welcome, thanks!

Comment: Is there only one candidate per county*district, as in your example? Is the number of rows per candidate always the same?

Comment: Im confused by the column `candidate` in the output, how is that determined?

Comment: So sorry! I corrected it now. It's just an order indicator of the candidate within each district

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option (also ignoring the issue with `candidate`. You can just summarize each group by taking the first instance of non-NA

```r
library(tidyverse)

current_df |>
  group_by(county, district) |>
  summarise(across(everything(), ~first(.[!is.na(.)])))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#> # Groups:   county [4]
#>   county district candidate name  votes party
#>   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 E100          1         1 john    100 D    
#> 2 E101          2         4 maria   200 I    
#> 3 E202          1         7 tom      78 R    
#> 4 E204          3        10 jose    120 R
```

or another option. Fill the NA by group and select first instance:

```r
current_df %>%
  group_by(county, district)|>
  fill(everything(), .direction = "updown") |>
  filter(row_number() == 1)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#> # Groups:   county, district [4]
#>   county district candidate name  votes party
#>   <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 E100          1         1 john    100 D    
#> 2 E101          2         4 maria   200 I    
#> 3 E202          1         7 tom      78 R    
#> 4 E204          3        10 jose    120 R
```

Comment: Thank you! but this is filling the NA for name jose as R, and it should be NA

Comment: Your original data would have had jose as R.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry that was a mistake I now corrected

Comment: My first solution still works. It would result in Jose as NA

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution until the column `candidate` is fully explained

```
library(tidyverse) 

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>% 
  select(-candidate) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(1:2)) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, 
              values_from = value)

# A tibble: 4 × 5
  county district name  votes party
  <chr>  <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 E100   1        john  100   D    
2 E101   2        maria 200   I    
3 E202   1        tom   78    R    
4 E204   3        jose  120   R
```

Comment: Thank you! but this is filling the NA for name jose as R, and it should be NA

Comment: @AntVal Just for no reason at all? This should be explained

Comment: Sorry it was unclear again. I corrected it now and it should make sense. sorry!